# Multiple Counts (of transaction type) in single SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

So I have a table for all transactions of a business, very simply it has a payment method column that lists how all the transactions were conducted, Cash, Credit or Debit.

What I want to do is create with the query two columns that count out how each transaction was completed, one column being Cash, the other being Card which would include all Credit and Debit purchases.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) as CashTransactions
FROM Transaction
WHERE PaymentMethod='Cash'
```

And what I want the output to be is

```
Cash Transactions  |       Card Transactions

 (Count of Cash)   |  (Count of Credit AND Debit)
```

Comment: Good question. A better question would be to display the fact that you have researched your question before posting it here.  Look at [Before you ask](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before). Have you searched Stackoverflow? How about the web?  Why didn't what you found solve your problem? Display what you have researched in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options here. I strongly suggest option one, it's cleaner and faster.

**Option 1**:

```
SELECT PaymentMethod, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfTransactions
FROM Transaction
GROUP BY PaymentMethod
```

Resulting in:

```
PaymentMethod | NumberOfTransactions
------------------------------------
Cash          | 33
Credit        | 12
Debit         | 87
```

Or **Option 2**:

```
SELECT (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfTransactions
FROM Transaction
WHERE PaymentMethod = 'Cash'
) as CashTransactions,
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfTransactions
FROM Transaction
WHERE NOT PaymentMethod = 'Cash'
) as OtherTransactions
```

Resulting in:

```
CashTransactions| OtherTransactions
------------------------------------
33              | 99
```

Comment: thx bb, works like a charm.  Is there an easy way to make a percentage/frequency column too?  Or would that involve a massive sub query?

Answer (score 1):

If you use sql server, you can try this query:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN PaymentMethod='Cash' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CashTransaction,
   SUM(CASE WHEN PaymentMethod IN ('Credit','Debit') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CardTransaction 
FROM Transaction
```

But, if you use ms-access, in query, you can try this query:

```
SELECT sum(IIF(PaymentMethod='Cash',1,0)) as CashTransaction, sum(IIF(PaymentMethod in ('Credit','Debit'),1,0)) as CardTransaction
FROM Transaction;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sum up instead of count:

```
SELECT 
    ABS(SUM(PaymentMethod = 'Cash')) AS CashTransactions,
    ABS(SUM(PaymentMethod <> 'Cash')) AS CardTransactions
FROM 
    Transaction
```